# Count registered requests of current week?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a net application with a telerik radgrid control, which I bind with a stored procedure. The grid contains the count of users that are registered in the system grouped by year, month, and day.

Now I need to add a count for users registered in the current week. How can I do this if I only have a field that corresponds to the registered date?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  count(UserId) -- or whatever you are using per-user
from yourTable
where datediff(dd, YourDateField, getdate()) <= 7
```

Comment: I try your solution but I get the same result no matter the week number

Comment: @user773456 that query will get you a count of all the users in the past week.  If this is not what you wanted, then I must have misunderstood you.  Please clarify.

Comment: I want the count of users registered in the current week

Comment: @user773456 can you please post your table structure?  I'm having a hard time seeing where my query isn't getting what you're looking for.  It will retrieve the users registered in the past 7 days.